# JQuery bounce effect broken by Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bounce

I'm trying to bounce a popup on hover. I want the popup to be a Bootstrap (v3.0.0) panel.
The problem is, the panel changes it's width after the bounce effect.

Example: http://fiddle.jshell.net/YxRvp/

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: check this http://fiddle.jshell.net/YxRvp/1/

Comment: The problem is still there on my browser (Chrome)... Or did you just change the mark-up? Thanks for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add     `min-width:315px;` to `.poppy`

http://fiddle.jshell.net/YxRvp/10/

```
#poppy {
    position: absolute;
    top: 200px;
    left: 250px;
    width: 315px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #f9f9f9;
    display: none;
    z-index: 2;
    min-width:315px;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

[**DEMO**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/YxRvp/25/)

```
$('.hover').mouseenter(function (e) {
    $('#poppy').css('top', e.pageY).css('left', e.pageX);
    $('#poppy').effect("bounce", {
        times: 1
    }, 200);
    $('.overlay').show();
});

$('.hover').mouseleave(function () {
    $('#poppy').hide();
    $('.overlay').hide();
});
```

Comment: The popup shows on mouse position... interesting. Can I bind it to the button too? Let's say, centered and 10px above the button, always, even if the button changes place (for example due to appending text on a div above)

Comment: @binoculars you can do that :)